# How can I change my desktop dimensions for Ubuntu base image running in Termux?

Tags: display-resolution, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in Termux (via Andronix) and displaying it in a VNC Viewer app with the OpenBox window manager.

I would like the "desktop" or window manager display to fill the screen of my Android smartphone, with the correct dimensions, rather than zooming in on parts of a horizontal, rectangular screen.

Support from OpenBox has told me that the VNC Viewer controls the screen dimensions, but support from RealVNC says my computer operating system determines it.

What would be an easy way to change the screen dimensions from Ubuntu? Should I look for a Ubuntu config file or should I configure the VNC server (tigervnc)?

The contents of vncserver-start is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export USER=root
export HOME=/root

vncserver -name remote-desktop -localhost no :1
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `vncserver-start`?

Comment: sh-5.0# vncserver-start

New 'remote-desktop' desktop at :1 on machine localhost

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/localhost:1.log                                                                                                                            Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd localhost:1 to connect to the VNC server.

Comment: I was asking for the contents of the file `vncserver-start`, not its output. What is the output of `cat /usr/local/bin/vncserver-start` ? That should give the contents of the file. Also, please edit the question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the command `vncserver -name remote-desktop -geometry 1366x768 :1`, and a VNC session would be started in `localhost:1`, with screen resolution `1366x768`.

With some trial and error, you can find a resolution that matches your phone's screen, so that you would not have to zoom out or zoom in anymore.

Once you know the screen resolution that works for you, edit `vncserver-start` with the appropriate resolution.

```
nano /usr/local/bin/vncserver-start
```